# Fingerprint scanner not detected after Windows7 install

Tags: windows-7, installation, control-panel, fingerprint

I've just upgraded my Dell Studio15 from Vista to 7 and it has stopped recognising the fingerprint scanner.  I'm expecting to see Biometric Devices in the control panel (Start -> Control Panel -> Hardware & Sound -> Biometric Devices) but it is not listed and is not found during searches.

I've installed what I believe to be the correct drivers and Device Manager shows a fingerprint scanner being installed and working, but Windows just won't pick it up.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go check the **[Dell website](http://www.dell.com)** for the new **Windows 7 drivers**, since the oficial release you should be able to find them (if it is supported)

Edit: though it already seems you have it installed "properly", since it is recognized, I still would recommend looking at official drivers. I downloaded mine last week and it did change a few things compared to Vista.

Edit: [Direct link says Vista only...](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=W764&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=STUDIO1555&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=False&scanConsent=False)

Comment: Exact Model is Studio 1537.  Just looking through the site again.  I'd had a search through the Support pages but I was taken to the drivers page with the only drop-down option for OS being Vista.

Comment: So I saw :-( that makes things a little more complicated...

Comment: Don't see drivers for it at any other model type either...

Comment: Helpful, isn't it?  I might log a tech support issue and see what comes back.  May also try downloading the updates from http://www.digitalpersona.com/support_downloads_updates_driver_dp0002003/